# Color/background-color change animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, background-color

I'm trying to do animation of color change in jQuery. But it failed.
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/hoxoza/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
$("#circle").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        width:"300px",
        height: "300px",
        borderRadius: "150px",
        }, 2000);
});
```

I know there's one similar answer on Stack Overflow, but it's years ago. So I ask again for potential newer answer to this problem. :)

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI as well as jQuery? jQuery alone doesn't support colour animations

Comment: (I'm new to Javascript.) So is jQuery UI the same as jQuery?

Comment: No - it's an extension of jQuery. You need to include jQuery, then jQuery UI and/or any other jQuery extensions.

Comment: So all I need to do is to add another line <script src="..."> for jQuery UI?

Comment: That's correct! See the JS Bin link in my answer below - that's what I've done.

Comment: Haha, I'd seen that just after I sent this comment! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **jQuery UI** as well as jQuery, as jQuery alone doesn't support colour animations.

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/pazapuciwo/1/)

Comment: So, is there anything else like jQuery UI for an extension? I'd like to know more example. :D

Comment: If you don't want to load jqueryUI, you could also try the colour plugin for jquery, as sugested in the jquery.animate() documentation. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: Thanks for sharing the plugin! I've never heard of plugin for Javascript. I'm just trying to know more terms before starting using it in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Vanilla Javascript and CSS animations

You can do this with css animations. However, it will not be animated on older browsers which do not support CSS animations, which can be a good thing.

In my experience computers which are using browsers old enough to not support the animations are generally slow enough that animations would be a detriment to the user experience, so I would recommend this method.

As well, CSS animations render smoother with less overhead than jQuery animations.

No external libraries required, not even jQuery

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function () {
        if (this.className.indexOf('clicked') < 0) this.className += ' clicked';
        else this.className = this.className.replace(/ clicked/g, '');
    };
})();
```

```css
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: all .4s linear;
}
#circle.clicked {
    background: #eee;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```